# Why I couldnt detect my file is empty or not in C?

Tags: c, file, detect

I tried several ways to do it but I couldnt.
Code interview:

```
    file = fopen(filename,"r");
    int size=0;
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("couldnt open: %s\n",filename);
    }
    else if(size==0){
        fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(file);
        fclose(file);
        if (size ==0){
            printf("empty");
        }
    }
```

I also tried to feof function, foef(file) always returns same value it doesnt care about file is empty or not. Any help?

Comment: This seems to work on Linix.

Comment: Check the returned value of `fseek()` if it's `0` or `non 0`; there are files that cannot be seeked. Also note that `ftell()` returns a long and you may lose precision by casting it to int.

Comment: @dbush Try with a 4-GiB file.

Comment: `else if (size==0)` why? you initialise it to 0, so that's always true. best to post the full, actual code that others can copy, paste, and compile/run as-is.

Comment: Cuz ı want to check when file is empty, throw the exception for emptyness. Thats why else if statement includes size ==0.

Comment: @Jack it returns 0, ı just check it out. And ftell() returns 152. Why?

Comment: You shouldn't be using that method to get the file size. On linux, use `fstat()` and on Windows, use `GetFileSize()`.

Comment: You initialize `size` to 0 and then you test `if (size==0)` right after. That's strange. Is this your _actual_ code or did you made this code up?

Comment: @Archie What uderscore_d is saying is that when you check `else if(size==0){` after opening the file `size` is *always* 0 so there's no point in doing the check.

Comment: I could say else if( file != NULL ) but it doesnt matter that not the problem at all. Focus on the problem, that is not the problem that you are looking for !

Comment: @Archie if `ftell()` returns 152 then that's the size of your file, in bytes. I don't understand what you are asking then

Comment: Avoid narrowing issues: `int size=0;` --> `long size=0;` and check `ftell(), fseek()` return values for errors.

Comment: "And ftell() returns 152. Why?" -->the most likely reason is because the file is about that length.  Try code that creates and empty file and so encapsulates the problem: [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You opened the file in text mode, then used `fseek()` with `SEEK_END`.

On the other hand, the standard says that only `SEEK_SET` should be used for `fseek()` with text stream.

Therefore, your code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.9.2 The fseek function:

> 4
> For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by
> an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file
> and whence shall be SEEK_SET.

Quote from N1570 4. Conformance:

> 2
> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-
> constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Note that some systems such as Linux treat text and binary files the same, so while this is undefined per the C standard, some OSs will allow it as an extension.

Comment: Read as   either ( offset shall be zero,) or (offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be SEEK_SET), implies `fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);` is fine and not UB.

Comment: C has "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream...".  Using `SEEK_END` with a binary file is potential UB